# International Driving Permit issued in India, is valid in US or not?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, florida

I have IDP issued by RTO, Gujarat. I want to know if this is valid in the US. I heard that it can vary per state. I am in Florida, so does Florida state permit an IDP issued in India or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IDP is only valid together with a regular driver's license. It might be necessary or not but it does not replace the original license. In Florida, it's actually [not necessary to have an IDP anymore](http://www.flgov.com/2013/04/02/governor-scott-signs-international-drivers-license-bill-at-florida-chamber-of-commerces-international-days/).

So the real question is wether your original license is recognized in the relevant jurisdiction. Apparently, all licenses from countries party to the 1949 Geneva Convention on Road Traffic (which India is) allow **tourists** to [drive in the US](https://www.justlanded.com/english/United-States/USA-Guide/Travel-Leisure/Driving-Licence). So you should be fine, at least if you are only visiting for a short time.

Comment: Let's make this the go-to answer for all related questions.

Comment: Your second source recommends getting an IDP anyway if your license doesn't have a photo or is written in a language other than English to avoid delays caused by needing to confirm that the ID is what you say it is.

Comment: @Relaxed, thanks for answer, I have IDP and Original license. Once again thanks for information.